# Perl: Index of array returned from method

Tags: arrays, perl, methods, indexing

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use feature qw(say);

my $raw_text = "a b c d e f g h";

my @array = split(/ /, $raw_text);
my $element = @array[0];

say "Element [0] of array is : ", $array[0];
```

This prints on STDOUT:

```
Element [0] of array is : a
```

So far, so good. However if I want to retrieve the element straightforward from the split method, I would think of:

```
my $element = split(/ /, $raw_text)[0];
```

But it turns out that this throws a compilation error. Doing some research I figured out that I have to type:

```
my $element = ( split(/ /, $raw_text) )[0];
```

The question is: **Why are the extra parenthesis necessary?**

I might be missunderstanding the parenthesis meaning for this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax error is to force you to disambiguate the expression, which could be interpreted as either

```
split((/ /, $raw_text)[0])
```

or

```
(split(/ /, $raw_text))[0]
```

In general, Perl will make a "best guess" at the intention of ambiguous code, but in this case the designers decided that there was no real way to decide on a "most likely" interpretation, and so caused the construct to fail in compilation to force the author to disambiguate the code

Note that the *inner* parentheses are superfluous, and the expression may be written like so

```
(split / /, $raw_text)[0]
```

Comment: I would have never thought of writing the expression as `(split / /, $raw_text)[0]`. Certainly, it makes much more sense now. Thank you!